# no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Traffic_light' to 'Traffic_light&'

Tags: c++

I am trying an example from the book "The C++ Programming Language". And there is an example of `enum` operator definition.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum Traffic_light {
    green,
    yellow,
    red
};

Traffic_light& operator++(Traffic_light& t)
{
    switch(t) {
        case Traffic_light::green: return t=Traffic_light::yellow;
        case Traffic_light::yellow: return t=Traffic_light::red;
        case Traffic_light::red: return t=Traffic_light::green;
    };
};

int main()
{   
    Traffic_light next = ++Traffic_light::yellow;
    return 0;
}
```

However when I try to compile it I've got an error

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:22:23: error: no match for 'operator++' (operand type is 'Traffic_light')
  Traffic_light next = ++Traffic_light::yellow;
                       ^
main.cpp:22:23: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:11:16: note: Traffic_light& operator++(Traffic_light&)
 Traffic_light& operator++(Traffic_light& t)
                ^
main.cpp:11:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Traffic_light' to 'Traffic_light&'
```

I compile it using this command in cmd

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe --std=c++11
```

What's the problem?

Comment: `++Traffic_light::yellow` is very similar to `++1` -- it tries to modify a constant.

Comment: In addition, the postfix operator is overloaded but the prefix operator is used.

Comment: Well the solution `Traffic_light item = Traffic_light::yellow; Traffic_light& next = ++item;`. I assigned it to another value. It seems that it indeed was trying modify the constant. It is not exactly the same example. In the example there was `Traffic_light next = ++light;`

Comment: So the above is not an example from the book, despite your claim?  Don't slander the poor book like that!

Comment: This is not an example from the book. Please correct the question so that it's clear.

Comment: @interjay: Where's the missing return statement?

Comment: ref. Fourth edition, page 51. In bright blue text.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I missed the `return`s hidden inside the `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to common implementations of operator++, that is

```
// preincrementation
Enum& operator++( Enum &c ) {
  // do incrementation logic
  return *this;
}

// postincrementation
Enum operator++( Enum &e, int ) {
  Enum old = e;  // copy old state
  ++e;           // increment in therms of preincrement
  return old;
}
```

but since you would like to call preincrementation operator on a temporary, i.e

```
Traffic_light next = ++Traffic_light::yellow;
```

then you have to diverge from this pattern and you may want to write operator++ this way:

```
#include <iostream>

enum Traffic_light { green, yellow, red, END};

Traffic_light operator++( Traffic_light t)
{
    // increment
    t = static_cast< Traffic_light>( static_cast<int>(t) + 1 );

    // wrap if out of range
    if ( t == Traffic_light::END )
        t = static_cast< Traffic_light> (0);

    return t;
};

Traffic_light operator++( Traffic_light l, int)
{
    Traffic_light t = l;
    ++l;
    return t;
};

int main()
{   
    Traffic_light nextPre = ++Traffic_light::yellow;
    std::cout << nextPre; // prints 1

    Traffic_light nextPost = Traffic_light::yellow++;
    std::cout << nextPost; // prints 2

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/Ixm7ax

Comment: The parameter type for operator++ is expected to be a reference because the standard usage is for it to modify the value. The correct fix here is to avoid using `++` on a constant rather than removing the reference.